# Linq-To-Sql optimization for queries

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I am building a web application which searches its `SQL` database for the query entered by the user. A simple search engine.
Lets propose I have plenty of rows - above a couple of thousands. I want to make the call efficient.
I know that my call is possible with only one* `SQL` query. I would like to know if `Linq-To-Sql` does this type of optimization.
I am aware the it uses `Lazy` for its queries. I cannot benchmark it now because I don't have enought data on my database.

```
    foreach(var word in words)
    {
        var niqquh = number == 666 ? "" : Languages[number];
        var S = db.Uploads.Where(w => number == 666 ? true : (w.Language == niqquh));
        if(S.Count() > 20)
            S = S.Take(20);
        S = S.OrderBy(u => (u.Tags.Contains(word) ? 15 : 0) + (u.Name.Contains(word) ? 10 : 0) + (u.Description.Contains(word) ? 5 : 0));
        listOfList.Add(S.ToList());
    }
```

As you see here, I have the 'magic number' `666` which is used to say "whatevery language is ok".
Then, I want to take only the top 20 elements, so I call `Count()` and then `Take`.
Then, I sort the results by my needs. 
The point is, that I *think* that the `lazy` expression gets evaluated at `Count` - therefore it cannot be optimized to contain *only* the top 20 rows at the `SQL Query` level - but on the client's (ASP.NET) level. therefore, I basically download the whole database to the client, which is terrible.
**Does it get optimized or not, if it doesn't, how can I do it in an efficient way, even if I have to go back to plain `SQL` string statements?**

*A query for each `word`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(S.Count() > 20)
```

This runs a query, yes...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
```

So you didn't download the whole table.

---

```
S = S.Take(20);
```

This does not execute the query.  It does limit the (unordered) query to 20 items.  Generally you want to apply order before you limit the result.

There is no exception if you Take more than is there.  You'll just get fewer items.  Because of this, the Count is not needed.

---

```
S.ToList();
```

This runs a query.

---

```
IQueryable<Upload> query = db.Uploads;
if (number != 666)
{
   var niqquh = Languages[number];
   query = query.Where(w => w.Language == niqquh);
}
query = query
  .OrderBy(u => (u.Tags.Contains(word) ? 15 : 0) + (u.Name.Contains(word) ? 10 : 0) + (u.Description.Contains(word) ? 5 : 0))
  .Take(20);
listOfList.Add(query.ToList());
```

Answer (score 5):

You are right, it will need to execute the statement to get the count. You don't need to check the count, however. So, change

```
if(S.Count() > 20)             
    S = S.Take(20);
```

to

```
S = S.Take(20);
```

It could be rewritten like this:

```
foreach(var word in words)
{
    var niqquh = number == 666 ? "" : Languages[number];
    var S = db.Uploads.Where(w => number == 666 || w.Language == niqquh)
        .Take(20)
        .OrderBy(u => (u.Tags.Contains(word) ? 15 : 0) + (u.Name.Contains(word) ? 10 : 0) + (u.Description.Contains(word) ? 5 : 0));
    listOfList.Add(S.ToList());
}
```

Comment: I thought so... I'll wait for more answers.